# Question about lowering the resolution of a 1Dspectrum (using specutils/astropy)

Tags: python, astropy, astronomy, spectrum, specutils

so mainly my main issue resumes in this

-) I have this high resolution spectrum (lets call it Model) and I want to lower it into a lower resolution (lets call it experimental), to compare both and see if the experimental behavior is in the model

-) I already know the  experimental resolution I want to smooth into and also I know the Model high resolution Im working with

For that Im using both specutils gaussian smooth and also astropy convolve. And also tried using the FluxConservingResampler from specutils

For what I did, now, both convolution functions (the astropy and specutils one) work with a gaussian kernel

`gaussian_smooth(Spectrum, stddev=sigma)` for the specutils method

`convolve(Spectrum.flux,kernel)` for the astropy one

now, when looking the kernel in the astropy method I can also use the function

`kernel=Gaussian1Dkernel(sigma)` so at the end both of these use standard deviation/sigma.

Here is where my problem exists, for the sigma Ive been using the FWHM relationship

`sigma = FWHM / (2 * np.sqrt(2 * np.log(2)))`

And this FWHM is calculated using the experimental resolution.

After doing the convolution, yeah I can see the spectrum is indeed smoothed BUT what causes me confusion is

How do I know the spectrum is indeed smoothed to the resolution I want?
is there a way to actually apply the experimental resolution into the smoothing? like ''I want to lower to this resolution''

Ive thought in doing a scaling factor, for example

model_resolution/experimental_resolution, but I really dont know how to apply it in code.

If anybody can help me that would be the best of the best Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is an expression for Resolving power R = wavelength/FWHM. In this case, if FWHM is fixed, the resolving power is higher for higher wavelengths.